# What is being changed the 'Render Tree' or 'DOM/CSSOM' whenever I update any style or add/remove a node from the DOM by using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, rendering

So once we receive html and css files from the server, the browser constructs a DOM and CSSOM, DOM + CSSOM gives us the 'Render Tree' which consists of only elements that would get displayed to viewport and then we have 'Layout' and 'Paint' phase. I want to know which tree is being changed whenever I change a style or add/remove a node using JavaScript after the page has loaded completely?